# GoLang Empty Struct Construction

Tags: go

Can someone explain why this

```golang
m := map[string]struct{}{"hello": {}}
```

is valid go code but this

```golang
c := make(chan struct{}, 1)
c <- {}
```

is not? It seems like I'm able to construct the struct via just `{}` in the first statement but I need to do `struct{}{}` for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not apples to apples. If you try this instead, you get same error:

```
package main

func main() {
   m := make(map[string]struct{})
   m["hello"] = {} // syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
}
```

As to your greater question, I believe that is answered here [1]:

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type `T`, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of `T`.

So for example, if you have a composite literal:

```
map[string]struct{}
```

where elements are also composite literal:

```
struct{}
```

Then you can omit the type:

```
{}
```

1. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

Comment: Given the behavior of statement two this is expected. I guess the question becomes why is it not apples to apples?

Comment: To be more specific, there's no reason the compiler can't always know I'm trying to give it an empty struct. It knows that because of the type of the map. There's nothing special about the environment of the constructor which makes it a special case

Comment: Makes sense. Still doesn't answer the "when is type inference ok?" question. In the second statement it's still very possible for the compiler to infer the type as `struct{}`. We can look at the operator `<-` and the LHS `c`. We know that `c` has type `chan struct{}`, therefore the RHS _must_ have type `struct{}`. It's not a technical limitation as far as I understand.

Comment: This is a guess, but I think it is related to the grammar. The map declaration uses `element: expression | literalValue`, which accepts `{}`, but channel send uses an expression, which requires `struct{}`. This is by looking at: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/golang/GoParser.g4

Comment: Oh interesting. I'm assuming the golang directory isn't officially maintained/supported by golang but "reverse engineered" somewhat. I suppose this still doesn't answer the why question but is cool nonetheless.

Comment: The parser is written manually, but follows the grammar pretty closely as far as I can tell: see go/parser/parser.go in stdlib, parseValue function. As to why this is written as such, I don't know. You might try the golang-nuts mailing list, Go authors usually answer there.